# Jquery Horizontal scroll to end

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve when user click on button then Horizontal scroll bar will drag to right side end.
I test below code which scroll to some distance but not reaching at the end of right side.

how to achieve what i am trying. thanks

```
<style>
    .outerWrapper {
        width: 30em;
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>

<input type='button' class='rightArrow' value='Click Me'>

<div class='outerWrapper'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
    
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".rightArrow").click(function () {
            //alert('www ' + $('.outerWrapper').outerWidth());
            var leftPos = $('.outerWrapper').scrollLeft();
            var divwidth = $('.outerWrapper').outerWidth();
            $(".outerWrapper").animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos + divwidth }, 800);
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: see my updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution what i was looking for. sharing the code.

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".rightArrow").click(function () {
            var leftPos = $('.outerWrapper').scrollLeft();
            var divwidth = $('.outerWrapper')[0].scrollWidth;
            $(".outerWrapper").animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos + divwidth }, 800);
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

this is key part **$('.outerWrapper')[0].scrollWidth** thanks